# Create list of lists iteratively

Tags: r

I have a loop that repeats 100 times each time creating three objects e.g.:

```
a<-TRUE
b<-1:20
c<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=2,nrow=10)
```

at the end of the first iteration I store these objects in a list:

```
myList<-list(a,b,c)
```

at the second iteration new `a b` and `c` are created which is stored in the same list overwriting the previous `abc`:

```
myList<-list(a,b,c)
```

Instead of overwriting the list I would like to add the new `abc` to the existing list.

Can the list be updated on each iteration to avoid overwrting it?

Can someone help?

Comment: Use `lapply()` instead of a loop.

Comment: that's not possible because it's a huge simulation with 100 lines of code. the list would store the results of the whole simulation

Comment: So? You can still use `lapply`.

Comment: you mean use lapply to execute a bunch of other apply functions and loops within?

Comment: @Rich Scriven has answered your question here URL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153263/adding-elements-to-a-list-in-for-loop-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the issue, you want a place to store your 100 lists. If so at the beginning do;

```
myList<-vector("list",100)
```

You now have a empty list with 100 slots. After each loop assign your output list to the correct slot. That is for iteration  34 put the output in `mylist[[34]]`. Each entry in `myList` will itself be a list of your results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
fun <- function() {
  #insert here as much code as you desire
  a<-TRUE
  b<-1:20
  c<-matrix(data=NA,ncol=2,nrow=10)

  list(a, b, c)
} 

replicate(100, fun(), simplify=FALSE)
```

If your function depends somehow on the iteration, you should use `lapply` instead.

Comment: but the problem is that on each iteration the previous a,b,c are overwritten so I don't see how this solves the issue

Comment: If this doesn't do what you need, you haven't explained your problem well enough.

Comment: Well, your edit doesn't change the fact, that my asnwer does what you claim to want.