# Adding elements to a nested list in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-lists

I am trying to add elements to a nested lists in a loop, but I cannot get it to work. The problem is that I need to use the nested names for positioning values, e.g. nested_list[["test1"]][["test2]], so I cannot just use the indices.

```
nested_list <- list()
list_of_nested_node_names <- c("test1", "test2", "test3")
position_in_list <- "nested_list"

for (i in 1:length(list_of_nested_node_names )) {
  position_in_list <<- paste(position_in_list, "[[\"", list_of_node_names[i], "\"]]", sep = "")
  eval(parse(text=position_in_list)) <<- list(1)
}
```

The issue has been discussed before in the following thread for adding to a list, but not for a nested list:
[Adding elements to a list in for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153263/adding-elements-to-a-list-in-for-loop-in-r)

Howcome I can print the "position_in_list" in the loop, and I can evaluate the string by using "eval(parse(text=position_in_list))", but I cannot place data in the structure?

Comment: I think this is an x-y-problem i.e. there's probably a more r-like approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval()`, well, evaluates the expression, so it doesn't really make sens on the LHS of an assignment.

You could make it work with:

```
for (i in 1:length(list_of_nested_node_names )) {
  position_in_list <- paste(position_in_list, "[[\"", list_of_nested_node_names[i], "\"]]", sep = "")
  eval(parse(text = paste(position_in_list, "<- list(1)")))
}
```

(Evaluating the whole assignment).

(Also, I don't see the need of the double-arrow assignment here).

Comment: Thanks! That is so simple, yet so effective. I cannot believe, I did not think of that. Great solution!